# How can I wait for the DOM to load in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `<template is="dom-if" if="[[shouldLoad(name)]]" class="render-me">`.

`name` is populated by data received in an ajax call, and that same data is used within the template. Unfortunately, this causes async issues.

Is there a way to reload the `dom-if` and wait for everything to render?

Answer (score 1):

Polymer offers several functions that can be found under [Lifecycle callbacks](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements) in the documentation.
In your scenario the ready function will probably work best.
 It is called after property values are set and the local DOM is initialized.

```
  ready: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' has local DOM initialized');
  },
```

Maybe you could add the function shouldLoad(name) to your question so we can see what exactly it does as there are other ways to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldLoad(name)` will re-evaluate when the value of `name` changes. Maybe, you can check the return value of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean when you get the answer from the server.

If you truly don't want things to render before thatt, add `restamp` as a property to the dom-if. If you don't have that, then Polymer will still render everything but hide it.

But if you got something that goes wrong, then it's probably something that goes wrong with your code. Oh, and dom-ifs doesn't render anything if the variable - `name` in that case - is `undefined`.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/elements/dom-if